# Problem with Gatsby app deployment on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, gatsby, package.json

I have problem with deployment of my Portfolio on Heroku. I read multiple articles, tutorials and answers on Stack Overflow, but it still doesn't resolve my problem.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Daniel Rolewski's personal website.",
  "author": "DanielRolewski",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.1",
    "npm": "6.14.8"
  },
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "heroku/nodejs"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static"
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "start": "gatsby develop -p 5000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "gatsby": "^2.30.2",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-alias-imports": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.12.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.9.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.10.1",
    "gsap": "^3.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.17.0"
  }
}
```

and my `heroku logs`:

```
2021-07-14T14:49:02.111197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-07-14T14:49:02.196230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-07-14T14:49:02.358675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-07-14T14:49:02.572895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-14T14:49:03.913083+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=danielrolewski-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=d82d115e-6694-423a-b781-fa5f17ea994c fwd="176.221.123.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-14T14:49:04.759144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=danielrolewski-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=20d739d5-b2e3-45ee-ac19-24fe81a39c1c fwd="176.221.123.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-14T14:49:04.925571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=danielrolewski-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=6e13f76f-b6ae-4d58-a988-d28283eec6c5 fwd="176.221.123.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

After change:
`"start": "gatsby develop -p 5000"`
To:
`"start": "gatsby serve"`

I have:

```
2021-07-14T15:15:27.903302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-07-14T15:15:27.952418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-07-14T15:15:28.080741+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-07-14T15:15:28.172552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-14T15:15:29.648616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=danielrolewski-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=5a31bb31-bcda-4048-9f21-05654e6cba75 fwd="176.221.123.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-07-14T15:15:29.748779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=danielrolewski-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=ab0ee939-a3c1-4895-aac6-5df07f8df0ab fwd="176.221.123.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-14T15:15:29.807695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=danielrolewski-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=c4c82eb5-2782-42c7-8edc-d2d5d65aab84 fwd="176.221.123.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

I have tried multiple things, but none of them work. Any ideas please?

Comment: `Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch` - you explicitly set `-p 5000`, so it's ignoring the port Heroku's trying to bind it to. Also you probably shouldn't be using `gatsby develop` in production at all.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I've changed in `package.json` "start" to: "start": "gatsby serve" but then I have this in `heroku logs`: https://pastebin.com/vsGdwytQ

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an up-to-date [mre].

Comment: You're _still_ not using the supplied PORT.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it! I literally changed nothing and after 30 same deploys it works fine.